# Problems with ng-show in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ng-if

I have a problem whit ng-show or ng-if in AngularJS, because I have, for example, this code:

```
  <div id="publicidad-principal" ng-if="publicidadPrincipal"></div>
```

and in the controller I have the correct way:

```
  $scope.publicidadPrincipal = false;
```

Now, when I open the page, for a second i see the DIV and then it is hidden, my question is: are there any way to have the div all the time hidden? then you can push a button and show it, but this is not the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
<div id="publicidad-principal" ng-show="publicidadPrincipal" ng-cloak></div>
```

And [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak) is the documentation for ngCloak.